# Why was this question deleted by "Community"?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775673/parsing-a-datetime-difference-in-days-to-an-integer

Seems somewhat arbitrary to nuke it from orbit as a moderator.

Comment: That seems to be the outcome of a user deletion.

Comment: Auto-deleted; a downvoted question from a deleted user.

Comment: Well it's a waste and there's good content on that question. The world is a darker place for this change.

Comment: @MattJoiner: I can't say I agree; the premise of that question is wrong, actually. There are plenty of better questions on Python datetime arithmetic available.